# SELECT SUM of columns from multiple table and group by id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following data

purchase_rec_a

```
+----------+------------+----------------+
| user     | date       | total          |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 1510     | 2018-08-08 | 5              |
| 1510     | 2018-09-12 | 10             |
| 1510     | 2018-09-19 | 15             |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

purchase_rec_b

```
+----------+------------+----------------+
| user     | date       | total          |
+----------+------------+----------------+
| 1510     | 2018-05-08 | 10             |
| 1510     | 2018-07-02 | 15             |
+----------+------------+----------------+
```

I can LEFT JOIN both tables by following sql

```
SELECT u.id, a.date, a.total AS total_a, b.date, b.total AS 
total_b
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN purchase_rec_a AS a ON u.id = a.user
LEFT JOIN purchase_rec_b AS b ON u.id = b.user
WHERE u.id =1510
```

and I get the following

```
+-------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| id    | date       | total_a | date       | total_b |
+-------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| 1510  | 2018-08-08 | 5       | 2018-05-08 | 10      |
| 1510  | 2018-08-08 | 5       | 2018-07-02 | 15      |
| 1510  | 2018-09-12 | 10      | 2018-05-08 | 10      |
| 1510  | 2018-09-12 | 10      | 2018-07-02 | 15      |
| 1510  | 2018-09-19 | 15      | 2018-05-08 | 10      |
| 1510  | 2018-09-19 | 15      | 2018-07-02 | 15      |
+-------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

so what I'm trying to do here is to group them in distinctive way by total_a and total_b and group by user so I tried

```
SELECT u.id, a.date, SUM( a.total ) AS total_a, 
b.date, SUM( b.total ) AS total_b
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN purchase_rec_a AS a ON u.id = a.user
LEFT JOIN purchase_rec_b AS b ON u.id = b.user
WHERE u.id =1510
```

and the result is

```
+------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| id   | date       | total_a | date       | total_b |
+------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| 1510 | 2018-08-08 | 60      | 2018-05-08 | 75      |
+------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

but the problem here is some data are duplicated and they are added as total

my expected result are below

```
+------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| id   | date       | total_a | date       | total_b |
+------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| 1510 | 2018-08-08 | 30      | 2018-05-08 | 25      |
+------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

I can get the above result by multiple SQL but I want it in single SQL, is it possible?

Comment: Please tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: you mean like mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the data "side-by-side", I would suggest `union all` and `group by`:

```
select user, date, sum(a_total) as a_total, sum(b_total) as b_total
from ((select user, date, total as a_total, 0 as b_total
       from purchase_rec_a
      ) union all
      (select user, date, 0 as a_total, total as b_total
       from purchase_rec_b
      )
     ) ab
group by user, user_date;
```

If you don't want date in the result, you can use the same structure, just changing the outer query:

```
select user, sum(a_total) as a_total, sum(b_total) as b_total
from ((select user, date, total as a_total, 0 as b_total
       from purchase_rec_a
      ) union all
      (select user, date, 0 as a_total, total as b_total
       from purchase_rec_b
      )
     ) ab
group by user;
```

Comment: thanks for your help, yes I forgot to mention date does not matter, I just want to group total_a and total_b, Ill try your solution :)

Comment: @ha_ryu . . . That is what the second solution does.

Comment: thanks for your help! your solution number 2 was the answer I was looking for, it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables  using sub-query

```
 select t1.user,a_total,b_total from

  (
select user, sum(total) a_total from purchase_rec_a group by user
  )
  join 

  (select user, sum(total) b_total from purchase_rec_b group by user
   ) t2 on t1.user=t2.user
```